# Make The Index1.php disappear at the end of the domain url. ( showing on home page )

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am doing an update on a project. Its default front page url is `www.test.com/index1.php`. I want to hide this index1.php from the url. I tried the below rewriterule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond $1 !^(index1\.php|resources|robots\.txt)    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But now it shows the url `www.test.com/index1.php`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Having `$1` as the first parameter of `RewriteCond` makes no sense. The first parameter is meant for whatever variable you want to attempt to match, and the second parameter is the pattern you want to match with.

In a `RewriteRule`, the first parameter is the pattern you want to match, and the second parameter is the resource you want to redirect the user to. Here you can use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to match the parenthesis you've created in your pattern in the first parameter.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index1.php$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index1\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index1.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful if you included a brief explanation of what caused the problem, why your code fixes the problem, and a link to documentation where they can find out more.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt I was just writing it. :-)

Comment: @asitha See my answer, I updated it to fix your problem by adding a new RewriteRule.

Comment: @asitha, that's a very vague description. What error do you get?

Comment: I think this created an infinite loop. Try adding `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200` before the first RewriteRule...

Comment: added this code.then the content of the site doesn't displays